# Why can't I install "ia32-libs" (no candidate)?

Tags: multiarch

I want to install eagle cadsoft 6.2.0 on Ubuntu 11.10, eagle is 32bit compatible so I need to install ia32-libs but its giving the following error:

```
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
```

after using the command `sudo apt-cache search ia32` I got this:

```
grub-efi - GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (dummy package)
grub-efi-ia32 - GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-IA32 version)
grub-efi-ia32-bin - GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-IA32 binaries)
lsb-core - Linux Standard Base 4.0 core support package
lsb-cxx - Linux Standard Base 4.0 C++ support package
lsb-desktop - Linux Standard Base 4.0 Desktop support package
lsb-graphics - Linux Standard Base 4.0 graphics support package
lsb-printing - Linux Standard Base 4.0 Printing package
elilo - Bootloader for systems using EFI-based firmware
libasm0 - Disassembling engine provided to the ERESI framework
libasm0-dev - Disassembling engine provided to the ERESI framework
lsb-languages - Linux Standard Base 4.0 Runtime Languages package
lsb-multimedia - Linux Standard Base 4.0 Multimedia package
lsb-qt4 - Linux Standard Base 4.0 Qt4 support package
refit - graphical boot menu for ia32 and x64 EFI systems
ia32-libs-multiarch - Multi-arch versions of former ia32-libraries
microcode.ctl - Intel IA32/IA64 CPU Microcode Utility
```

please help.

Answer (score 6):

**You are already on a 32-bit system!**

- `ia32-libs`, or 32-bit compatibility libraries for 64-bit systems, is only available in the *amd64* repositories, i.e. if you are using a 64-bit version of Ubuntu.
- You only get the "no installation candidate" error if you are already on a 32-bit system.
- [As this page shows](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/ia32-libs), it is available for Ubuntu 11.10 *64-bit*.

You can run "32-bit compatible" packages such as Eagle Cadsoft on a 32-bit Ubuntu system **without needing to install *ia32-libs***. (Just try it :-)

Comment: I am geeting following error:/tmp/eagle-setup.26503/eagle-6.2.0/bin/eagle: error while loading shared libraries: libpng14.so.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @ravi: please include the output of `ldd /tmp/eagle-setup.26503/eagle-6.2.0/bin/eagle` as pastebin or in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
```

Comment: @tijybba I'm not sure if running that command would work, but this is undeniably an answer, and not a request for information. That command tries to install the multarch version of `ia32-libs` (though ordinarily `ia32-libs` should still exist, and be a virtual package for this, so I'm not sure under what conditions this would work). That command is not for diagnostic purposes; it is intended to actually fix the problem.

Comment: It said try with command without description about it , so i guess i commented on it , i will be deleting it , thanks @EliahKagan. AM sure i didn't downvoted it though.

Comment: @tijybba Well even if you did downvote it (which I understand you did not), I'm not disagreeing with the downvote. In fact, any answer you think should be deleted but *not* flagged for moderators is something you should probably strongly consider downvoting.

Comment: I will keep that in my senses @EliahKagan , thanks again sir.