# Why does my 64-bit system look for 32-bit repos?

Tags: apt, multiarch

I've got a 64-bit 12.10 install on my Laptop. When running apt-get update, it downloads package lists for 32-bit packages (as well as source and 64-bit package lists). Why does it look for 32-bit package lists on a 64-bit system? I've included one of the items it tries to find below.

```
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Confusing, isn't it? Let me explain a bit.

#### Why?

- 32-bit software runs fine on a 64-bit kernel with 64-bit capable hardware.
- Some software still relies on specific 32-bit libraries. This is not nice, but sometimes we don't have the power to change this.
- 32-bit software has to be available to the system to satisfy the dependencies, so it uses the 32-bit repositories as well.

#### I'm from early 2011. What happened?

In 64-bit versions of Ubuntu before 11.10, some set of common 32-bit libraries were packaged in a single `ia32-libs` package represented to APT/Dpkg as being 64-bit and in such a location in the repository. If you happen to need a single library for an application, it would depend on the 150+ MB of 32-bit libraries<sup>1</sup>. Clearly, this is not a nice design.

#### Multiple architectures?

The new idea was to introduce so-called "Multiarch" capabilities to APT/Dpkg and the tools around it. This was presented in several blueprints on Launchpad, [here is one of them](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/foundations-o-multiarch-next-steps). Oneiric (11.10) became the first release that supported Multiarch.

#### How does it work?

You can tell Dpkg what architectures your system is capable running. On my 12.04 64-bit installation, this is here:

```
$ cat /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch 
foreign-architecture i386
```

It opens the whole world of `i386` packages, with `amd64` still being the default:

```
$ apt-cache show libqt4-core                   | grep -E "^(Filename|Architecture)"
Architecture: amd64
Filename: pool/universe/q/qt4-x11/libqt4-core_4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3_amd64.deb

$ apt-cache show libqt4-core:i386              | grep -E "^(Filename|Architecture)"
Architecture: i386
Filename: pool/universe/q/qt4-x11/libqt4-core_4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3_i386.deb
```

The above example shows that Multiarch enables package maintainers to simply make their packages depend on `libqt4-core:i386` for example, and makes it possible to install *any* 32-bit library/package (and thus to install any package that *depends on* any 32-bit library/package), rather than a preselected set.

#### `ia32-libs` compatibility

In case you were used to install the `ia32-libs` package as a convenience package to install a common set of basic 32-bit libraries, you can now use [`ia32-libs-multiarch`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ia32-libs-multiarch) [image: Install ia32-libs-multiarch]. This is a simple metapackage depending on the same (or at least very similar) set of libraries, but it will be installed with the power of Multiarch.

#### Further related readings

- [Why can't I install "ia32-libs" (no candidate)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164538/why-cant-i-install-ia32-libs-no-candidate/164581#164581)
- [Ubuntu Community Wiki on MultiArch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch)
- [Ubuntu Official Wiki on the tech details and exact specification](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec)

<sup>1</sup> <sub>For Lucid (10.04) the [`ia32-libs` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ia32-libs) install size is 155,812.0 kB.</sub>

Comment: I recommend running `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` rather than catting `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch`. It doesn't exist after 12.04.

Comment: I've just setup apt-mirror at home and was hoping to just mirror the 64-bit repo. It's unfortunate that I cannot do that, but I understand why now and it makes sense this way. Answer accepted!

Comment: @tgm4883 You could remove the foreign architecture configuration if you really want to run `amd64` only. It's similar to running an older Ubuntu without `ia32-libs` available.

Comment: I started reading and in my mind it said: hmm  looks like a post from gertvdijk :+) Goede post ;)