# Ubuntu 12.10 64bit no /usr/lib32/?

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, 32-bit, libraries

I am currently trying to setup `wine` properly in Ubuntu 12.10. The error that I am trying to fix is:

```
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

I have found several Posts here which say that I have to create a symlink to the 32bit lib but when I look for `/usr/lib32` on my system then I see that I dont have any lib32 directory.

I tried to install the 32 libs with:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Terminal says I have already the newest version. But I still don't have any `/usr/lib32` directory.

I hope anyone can help me with that issue.

Comment: You're probably looking into outdated information. Ubuntu has Multiarch since 11.10, so you don't want to install `ia32-libs`, but the libraries you need as 32-bit, e.g. `sudo apt-get install gnome-keyring:i386`. That package [contains this very missing file](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=quantal&arch=any). See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/238043/88802) for more about Multiarch. (not sure if that solves your issue, so posting as a comment)

Comment: Ok, this explains my issue at least a bit. But how can I find out which i386 Libraries I need now and how can I install them?

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention. I tried to install the gome-keyring:i386 but I got this error:

`gnome-keyring:i386 : Depends: libcap-ng0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libgck-1-0:i386 (>= 3.3.90) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libgcr-3-1:i386 (>= 3.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: gcr:i386 (>= 3.4) but it is not going to be installed`

Ok I update the question.

Comment: Good question now. :) I can reproduce this on my system as well.